# How to add Google Adsense the static site

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I am trying to add Google Adsense in my static site.
I used

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-someid",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
```

in my head portion. I want to show ads in my header and sidebar. How to do it. Do I need more codes? I also need to show ads like in [this](https://i.ibb.co/qrhV2xN/Screenshot-20190607-121309.png)
My site [here](http://cararenashop.com)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Sign up for Google AdSense**

**2. Get the Matched content code :**

To generate your AdSense Matched content code you first need to create the ad unit. You can do this on the My ads tab in your AdSense account. There are a few different types of ad unit that you can choose from. You need to select a type called Matched content.

**My ads > Ad unit** then **+ New ad unit**. Select **Matched content**.
Click Save and get code !

Your Matched content code will be similar to the following one:

```html
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"> 
    </script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-format="autorelaxed"
         data-ad-client="0000000000000000"
         data-ad-slot="00000000"></ins>
    <script>
         (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

**3. Create a Jekyll widget**

In this step, you need to create a widget (template file with your Matched content code inserted), and then call it from the desired place on your website. I call it from right after the {{ content }}, but the placements is totally up to you. In my case an ads will be displayed at the end of each blog post, just above the comments section.

Create a file called **matched-content.html** in the _includes catalog of your Jekyll website.

- The name of this file is totally up to you, so you can name it whatever you like.
- Insert your Matched content code to this file.
- You got your Matched content code in the step 2 of this tutorial.
- Go into the _layouts catalog and find the **post.html** file (or any layout file for which you would like the Matched content unit displayed).

*Note: For best results, place your matched content unit directly below your article or in the sidebar.*

Call the Matched content widget by inserting the following code right after the {{ content }}:`

```html
{% include matched-content.html %}
```

And that's done !

Comment: So this code `<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-someid",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>` not needed?

Comment: I don't know where this code came from :) I think you want to show ads about "cars" (i saw your dropshipping website), so follow my steps to get it work !

Comment: Okey, But I can't find `Matched content` Option in new ad unit. Here is the [image](https://i.ibb.co/6WpXjgD/ads.png)

Comment: @JustineChacko do you have a google account linked with credit card ?